# Validating dates with day out of range

Tags: java, date

When I try to parse date `2020-06-31` java successful parse it despite the fact that June have only 30 days (result is 30th of June).

My code

```
DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMATTER =
            new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
                    .toFormatter();
LocalDate.from(DATE_FORMATTER.parse("2020-06-31"))
    .atStartOfDay()
    .atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur"))
    .toInstant();
```

Is it possible to validate such dates?

**PS**: I use `Java 1.8`

Comment: You could try to get that time in milliseconds, parse that time to a `LocalDate` (or similar) and compare the results. If those are not equal, the input is wrong.

Comment: I suspect parsing work consistent, so no matter how I'll parse I will get same result.

Comment: Yes but converting 06-31 to milliseconds and reconverting it to a date will result in 07-01

Comment: What Java version are you using? When I try to do `LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse("2020-06-31");` I get a `DateTimeParseException` that complains about an *Invalid date 'JUNE 31'*. That means I could `try`-`catch` invalid dates, at least...

Comment: I use 1.8. I doubht they let me upgrade :(

Comment: Well, that's my one, too... Maybe it's the default formatter that complains, but the one you built doesn't. Not sure... Will try your code.